# Columns of nested divs with the same set ratio rendering at slightly different heights

Tags: html, css, page-layout

I've split my page into two vertical divs, each containing a number of nested divs wrapped so that they resize preserving a set ratio. That works great - but for some reason the divs on the left end up *shorter* than the divs on the right! The CSS is consistant, but something's not...

You can see a gap appear at the foot of the left-hand column here:

http://jsfiddle.net/VsJLs/

Is it clear what's wrong? Thank you for looking!

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.break {
padding-top: 25px;
}
.leftcol {
width: 50%;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 25px;
}
.leftpad {
padding-right: 38px;
}
.rightcol {
width: 50%;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
right: 25px;
}
.rightpad {
padding-left: 37px;
}
.wrapper {
width: 100%;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
}
.wrapper:after {
padding-top: 161.3%;
display: block;
background-color: red;
content: '';
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="leftcol">
<div class="leftpad">
<div class="break"></div>
<div class="wrapper"></div>
<div class="break"></div>
<div class="wrapper"></div>
<div class="break"></div>
<div class="wrapper"></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="rightcol">
<div class="rightpad">
<div class="break"></div>
<div class="wrapper"></div>
<div class="break"></div>
<div class="wrapper"></div>
<div class="break"></div>
<div class="wrapper"></div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I've tried zeroing margins as suggested below but that doesn't improve things. It seems like the problem could lie with the `padding-top: 161.3%;` property. Changing `%` to `px` fixes that creeping misalignment - but I need to keep it as a percentage! Can anybody figure this out? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused due to the margin border; set it to 0 or same on all sides:

```
MARGIN
{BORDER=0;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15072409/columns-of-nested-divs-with-the-same-set-ratio-rendering-at-slightly-different-h/15072452#15072452

Comment: A friendly recommendation- please avoid using all caps on StackOverflow, as it's generally considered unprofessional.

Comment: Thanks both very much - I'm embarrassed to ask, but could you place that into the jsfiddle above and repost it? I've tried defining the margin but can't see any change. This seems hopeful though, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out - I mean: I know the problem but I'm still not sure *why*... The gutter I created was split unevenly:

```
.leftpad {
padding-right: 38px;
}
```

and

```
.rightpad {
padding-right: 37px;
}
```

If both those are equal (http://jsfiddle.net/VsJLs/1/) then there's no slip. Now I'm worried about creating columns this way - that's another question though...